# Get expression value from drools

Tags: drools

I want to get expression value from drools.The drl like this.

```
global java.util.Map $globalVar;
global java.lang.Object $result;

import java.util.Map;

function myFunc(Map map){
    return "hello";
}

rule "onlyone"
when
    $factMap: Map($tmpResult:(myFunc($globalVar)), eval(true))
then
    $result = $tmpResult;
end
```

When the rule get exception,like this

Caused by: org.mvel2.PropertyAccessException: [unable to resolve method: java.util.Map.$globalVar() [argslength=0]]

The global variable $globarVar has no relation with the fact.

It is likely drools can't recognize the global variable.Is there any grammar error in my drl?

Comment: Your function is missing a return type. And you can't use `eval(true)` like that.

Comment: Actually what are you even trying to do, that `Map( $tmpResults: ... )` thing makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is so wrong I can't even figure out what you're trying to do.

Functions are very simple, they're just like methods in Java. They even look like methods in Java -- yours is missing a return type.

```
function String myFunc(Map map) {
  return "hello";
}

function String greeting(String name) {
  return "Hello, " + name + ". How are you?"
}
```

You can invoke them in your rules as you would any other function, either on the left hand side ("when") or on the right hand side ("then").

```
rule "Apply Greeting and Send Memo"
when
  $memo: Memo( $recipient: recipient, sent == false )
  $greeting: String() from greeting($recipient)
then
  MemoSender.send($greeting, $memo);
  modify( $memo ) {
    setSent(true)
  };
end

rule "Apply Greeting and Send Memo - v2"
when
  $memo: Memo( $recipient: recipient, sent == false )
then
  String $greeting = greeting($recipient);
  MemoSender.send( $greeting, $memo );
  modify( $memo ) {
    setSent(true)
  }
end
```

The bits with the globals in your question are red herrings. Yes, they're not working and throwing errors, but the syntax is so wrong that I'm not sure how it was supposed to work in the first place.

One way you *might* interact with a global in a function would possibly be something like ...

```
global Float taxRate; // passed in as a global because it's an external constant value
global Float freeShippingThreshold;

function float calculateTotal(float subtotal) {
  // some math here that references taxRate
  return calculatedTotal
}

rule "Apply free shipping"
when
  Cart( $subtotal: subtotal )
  Float( this >= freeShippingThreshold) from calculateTotal($subtotal)
then
  // you get free shipping
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm newer to drools. What I want to do is just getting the temp value from lhs. For example . when Float(calculateTotal(subtotal) > 3), I want to get the value of calculateTotal(subtotal). And give it to the global variable.

Comment: So do that on the right hand side. But you can't rely on that updated global on the left hand side. But if you just want it to be your "output", that's fine -- it's the old fashioned way of getting data out of rules.